# Add a gap between UIViewController's view and bottom of the screen

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

How to add a gap between UIViewController's view and bottom of the screen. I need to have a UIView under all of view controller's inside the UINavigationController, so I need to programmatically add or remove this gap.

Comment: try to use tabBar view and insert there any view

Comment: @ConstantinSaulenco But I don't have any problem adding that bottom view, My issue is that I can't add the gap for all view controller's programmatically. `self.view.frame = CGRect(...)` not working anywhere

Comment: then use `self.navigationController.view.frame = yourFrame`

Comment: It works, Thank you very much :)